# why is this a not defined when it clearly is?

Tags: javascript

I'm a total newbie, trying to survive my JS assignments. Any help is welcome.
When I run the following code, I get an error message saying "a is not defined." But a is defined.

```js
function name(a, n) {
  let a = b;
  let b = x;
  let c = n;
  let b = c;
  return c + a;
}

console.log(name(a, n));
```

Comment: Bizarrely-written function. What is its intended purpose? Is it deliberate, just to test you?

Comment: That code has a bunch of issues. What is x and n? `function add (a, b) { return a + b; } console.log(add(1,2));`

Answer (score 2):

`a` is only defined inside the function.

You are trying to read `a` (and `n`) **outside** the function and pass the resulting values to the function.

Comment: I'm also wondering if any of the variables used for assignment inside the name function are declared outside of the function? If not, how could a be assigned to the value b?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you call the function name instead of this `console.log(name(a, n));` use this: `console.log(name(5, 10));`

As @Quentin said, when you pass the variables `a` and `b` to the function console log, it has to be defined outside of your function, but you can pass just the values and don't need to define the `a` and `b` variable outside the function.

Answer (score -1):

So many problems here...

```js
function name(a, n) {
  let a = b; // a is already declared in function's declaration
  let b = x; // x has never been declared
  let c = n;
  let b = c; // b is already declared in Line 3, additionally this line will make b = n
  return n + a;
  // this would finally become return b + b
  // because Line 4: c = n 
  // and Line 5: b = c
  // and Line 2: a = b
}

document.write(name(a,n)); // a and n should contain any value
```